# React with Typescript can not recive XSRF-TOKEN from spring application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, csrf, csrf-token

I have written a Spring Boot Application where I want to use CSRF protection.

For this I have set the Spring SecurityFilterChange with the following snipped:

```
.csrf(csrf ->
                        csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
                                .ignoringRequestMatchers(unprotectedMatcher))
                .addFilterAfter(new CookieCsrfFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Also I have added the CookieCsrfFilter for Spring 6 as described here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/06/17/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot

In chrome I see the cookie and the cookie is not marked as httpOnly, so JS/Typescript should load the cookie

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh93N.png)

In my React app, written in typescript I have set in the index.tsx the CookiesProvider as descript in the manual https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie

```
...
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CookiesProvider>
      <App />
    </CookiesProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

In my App.tsx I would like to read the XSRF-TOKEN, but the token is everytime undefined.

```
const [cookies] = useCookies(['XSRF-TOKEN']);

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (loggedIn) {
        console.log("XSRF-TOKEN: " +  cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']);
        fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/user/check", {
          headers: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'],
          },
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'include',
          }).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
             // logoutUser();
            }
          }); 
      }
    }, 10000);
```

Any idea what I can check or what the problem can be? Is there a Problem with the react-cookie and typescript?

I have tried to access to the cookie on several places in the Code.
Also debugging did not show me the reason. The only thing I have not seen, is that the  function onChange()in the useCookies.js is never called.

I found the reason why the cookie ist not readable.

My Boot application runs under another server.servlet.context-path like /myApp So the cookie has the path /myApp

The react app can not read the cookie because it is not located at the path "/".

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Instead of "I want to use CSRF" you probably want to say "I want to use CSRF protection". As for why "XSRF-TOKEN" is undefined, the reason is probably elsewhere in your code. Check which cookies the browser actually gets. Also this has nothing to do with TypeScript.